# Please clarify the meaing of "the emigrants made open profession of ..."

Tags: british-english, books

Can you help me to understand this sentence from a book?

> The emigrants made open profession of ... (Judaism)

Comment: I understand it in two way: 
1) they were doing some life-actions according to Judaism
or 
2) They were studying some concept of Judaism

Comment: You should add the name of the book (and the page) so that people can see the wider context of the expression.

Comment: Why would a sentence begin with a lowercase letter and contain an ellipsis followed by a single word in parentheses? Is this is only a snippet of a sentence? Or have you made some edits? It's unclear.

Comment: To those who would answer in comments: please don't. If you can answer in the Answer box, feel free to do so. Or vote to close, perhaps with a comment asking for more information if you think the question needs it.

Comment: The book is "frederick copleston - history of philosophy volume 4"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "profess" means to [affirm or declare your faith in something.](https://www.google.com/search?q=profess%20meaning&oq=profess%20meaning&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l7.8151j0j8&client=tablet-android-samsung&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8). It isn't related to the meaning of "profession " as in a job or career.

To "make open profession of Judaism" is to openly declare your belief in the Jewish faith.